# what is std::identity and how it is used?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I just want to know what is the purpose of std::identity? I could not find anything useful on web. I know how it is implemented :

```
template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    T operator()(T x) const { return x; }
};
```

why do we actually need this?

Comment: Standard doesn't have `std::identity`, all proposals have been removed. You might consider this as a hint.

Comment: the main use of the identity function is to be able to pass an argument wrapped around a function pointer if this is the argument expected. It is common in functional programming and tends to be used a lot in languages like haskell. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987085/what-do-people-use-the-identity-function-for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202474/default-function-that-just-returns-the-passed-value read this and you'll get it

Comment: then what is this? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity

Answer (score 5):

Other people already answered the question - it's useful for things like a *default* for a function-type template parameter, and for haskell-style functional programming.

But your example implementation is not correct. Your code would perform a value copy, which `std::identity` does not do - it perfectly forwards. It's also `constexpr` and is transparent.

So *this* is an example of how it would be implemented, I believe:

```cpp
    struct identity
    {
        using is_transparent = void;

        template <typename T>
        constexpr T&& operator()(T&& t) const noexcept
        {
            return std::forward<T>(t);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard (up to C++20) doesn't have `std::identity`, all proposals mentioning it have been removed. When initially suggested, it was supposed to serve the same purpose as `std::forward` serves in accepted standard, but it conflicted with non-standard extensions and after several iterations was finally removed.

C++20 has `std::identity` back: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity

Comment: @MEMS, VS extension.

Comment: Could you provide an example with which extensions it conflicted? And how?

Comment: @Yola - exactly in the comments above, VS extension!

Comment: C++20 adds `std::identity`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity

Answer (score 2):

The struct you have in your code is the identity function `T -> T` where T is a template parameter. This function isn't useful on its own, but may be useful in other contexts where you need to pass a function parameter and the identify function is the one you want insert there. It's generally useful as a sort-of "do nothing" function.

As to `std::identity`, I can find no evidence that this struct exists in the C++ standard library.

Comment: It's pretty useful to exclude arguments from template argument deduction. Cppreference has an example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: @Cubbi Unless I'm mistaken, the article you linked to seems to be talking about the identity type transformation rather than the identity function though. Similar concept, but not quite the same thing at least as far as C++ is concerned.

Comment: huh, indeed, now I also wonder what the Microsoft identity is for.

Comment: @Cubbi: indeed pretty handy. Boost clamp uses identity to prevent argument deduction for its other arguments but unfortunately std::clamp doesn't use that trick.

Answer (score 2):

While not relevant at the time of the question being asked, C++20 adds [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity) which seem to come from `Ranges` proposal. [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/functional/identity) is its previous definition from `Ranges TS` where the main usage of it is explained as:

> It is used as the default projection for all Ranges TS algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `std::identity` in my libraries, but it should be a useful tool to copy a vector into another one without the `nullptr` objects in it via `std::copy_if`.

Comment: so you mean it is mainly used to prevent processing void pointers?